# Is it possible to take the text inside of a element and display it ::Before css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a table, and was trying to figure out a more automatic way to fill in the `::before content: ' ';`

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th id="text">word</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

I was trying to use javaScript to do this.

```
table th:nth-child(1)::before {
    content: attr('');
}
```

is it possible to use javascript to get the text inside the id "text" and use it in css to display it using ::before "word"?

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3ez5gey5/ Not really clear what the issue is. Example is very trivial

Comment: it was doing it more of replacing the word "text" with "word" as the id

Comment: not clear what that means, replace id with text value? That doesn't make much sense either. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `:before` and other like it are pseudo elements and are actually, not part of the dom so you can't select them with javascript. However, if you generate the elements dynamically, you could include the content of pseudo elements as attributes on the actual element and use that instead from javascript

eg:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th id="text" before-content:"myBeforeContent">word</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

If you have a predetermined set of :before content values for example and you define all of them in a css file, you could split the :before in a single class, and use that to later make a connection with a map of contents in javascript

for example:

```
#myElement {

}

#myElement.redBeforeContentClass:before {
   content:"actual red content"
}
```

and in javascript, you could have a map like :

```
{
"redBeforeContentClass", "actual red content"
}
```

At this point, you could just make a match between a DOM object's class and your map of contents.

All this are just hacks to achieve the desired action, and they might require some work to get them to work, but still. If you really need to do this, that works

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trick here (you would need javascript as well).

In the CSS, you can write :

```
table th:nth-child(1)::before {
    content: attr(data-before-content);
}
```

And in javascript on the document ready function :

```
$(function() {
    $('table th:nth-child(1)').attr('data-before-content','new_value');
});
```

See if it changes, and if it does, you can change that dinamically.

Comment: ok so that gets me the value of "new_value", I think, I will be able to target what I need

Comment: so I repleaced the 'new_value' with the ID. var text = $('#text').text();

Answer (score 0):

One way with javascript is not worry about using `::before` and just prepend the id to existing text

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td:first').text(function(_, oldText){
        return this.id + ' ' + oldText;
   });
});
```

Or for more style control use `html()`

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td:first').html(function(_, oldHtml){
        return '<span class="ident">'+ this.id + '</span>' + oldHtml;
   });
});
```

Comment: This works if you don't have style on your pseudo elements. Otherwise, it is a bit more complicaed, but still doable in the manner you describe

Comment: @BoieriuAlexandru any style can be moved to the html  also